# Iterator python

Tags: python, iterator

I was trying to do something like this for example

```
def functionx(x):
    while x > 0:
        x = 2 + 2
        x -= 1

for x in functionx(x):
       print(x)
```

Well, in for I wanted to print `x = 2 + 2` but it just give me the direction where the function is.

Also just wanted to use `x = 2 + 2`, use it in another function but then use the stored number again and so on but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: at the end of the function instead the return that I forgot to write?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Also, do you have any other questions? I suggest you look into `yield`, a very powerful addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `yield` keyword.

Example

```
def functionx(x):
    while x > 0:
        x += 1
        yield x

for i in functionx(1):
    print i
```

This creates the `functionx` as an iterator.

Comment: I do not want to give a direct answer. I simply gave an "example". Also the OP'keeps setting the x to be 4 every time in the loop so I got rid of that.

Comment: thanks, I also made an example, guess it was wrong. Appreciate your help